# lvm2 pv format option is grayed out in gparted

Tags: gparted, lvm

I would like to format a partition to lvm2 pv with gparted, but the option is grayed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to format a partion as lvm2 pv, gparted needs the package lvm2 to be installed.

In a terminal run

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2
```

Then restart `gparted`